# libgdx: InputAdapter does not work when resumed from browser

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a `Screen` implementation with `InputMultiplexer` which is initialized in the `show()` method. The `InputMultiplexer` is initialized with `InputAdapter` and the `Stage` object.
The `InputAdapter` object listens for the back button.

```
class MyInputAdapter extends InputAdapter {
   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Keys.BACK) {
         // do someting
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyScreen implements Screen {
    @Override
    public void show() {
        initInputProcessors();
    }

    private void initInputProcessors() {
        if (backButtonInputProcessor != null) {
            initInputMultiplexer();
            Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMiltiplexer);
        } else {
            Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        } 
    }

    private void initInputMultiplexer() {
        if (inputMiltiplexer == null) {
            inputMiltiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
            inputMiltiplexer.addProcessor(backButtonInputProcessor);
            inputMiltiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        } 
    }
}
```

All works fine, and the back button reacts without any problem.
The problem occurs, in the following scenario. I use admob. So when clicking an ad banner, this brings you to browser. When you are back from browser to the app, the back button is not intercepted and the application just exits.

I also tried calling the `InitInputProcessors` method inside the `resume()` method, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question on LibGDX forum has solved it. Following is the [solution by skunktrader](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14938#p64848):

> Try adding this to your android MainActivity
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     theView.requestFocus();
>     theView.requestFocusFromTouch();
> }
> ```
>
> Where `theView` is the value returned from `initializeForView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `InputProcessor` as null in `hide()` method. Like this:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
}
```

Comment: It seems that the hide(), pause(), resume() methods inside the screen are not called at all. The Game instance methods pause() and resume() are called, and I am calling super.pause() and super.resume() in them to delegate it to the currently showing screen as described in the libgdx documentation. Is there some bug? I am using one of the nightly builds on top of 0.9.9. I saw that there is version 1.1.0 released already, I will try it out, whether it works otherwise there

Comment: Strange when I worked with libgdx 1.0 everything worked fine. Any of this methods are called when you click admob, and before browser is opened?

Comment: upgraded LibGdx to the latest 1.1.0 version. Now the pause() and resume() are called (hide() is not called in this scenario) inside the Screen implementation. But setting input processor to 'null' in pause and then reinitializing it on resume() didn't solve the issue. The application still does not captures the back button press.

Comment: I have debugged the AndroidInput class. It seems that even the onKey(...) method is not called in this case. Is there some bug in LibGDX? :(

Comment: more likely the way the run time is wired on the phone. those methods have to be called by android